# Using permutations to generate words

Tags: python

I am tyring to generate words after replacing the characters found in replacements dict. If x string is given...

```
x = 'sap'
```

return the possible words like...

```
x_result = ['sap', 'saq', 'sbp', 'sbq']
```

The replacement table is:

```
replacements = {'a':'b', 'b':'a', 'm':'n', 'n':'m', 'p':'q', 'q':'p'}
```

Here is another example:

```
y = 'map'
y_result = ['map', 'maq', 'mbp', 'mbq', 'nap', 'naq', 'nbp', 'nbq']
```

Comment: are the replacements always symentrical like that ? ... ie if you have "a":"b", you also have "b":"a"? or could it be `"a":"b","b":"c"` ?

Comment: does the order of x_result matter?

Comment: a > b > c is not possible.  order does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this by determining first the options for each position in the string

```py
x = "sap"
replacements = {"a":"b","b":"a","m":"n","n":"m","p":"q","q":"p"}
# use a set to eliminate duplicates...
subs = [{_x,replacements.get(_x,_x)} for _x in x]
print(subs) # [{'s'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'p', 'q'}]
```

this basically says

- the options for position0 is only "s"
- the options for position1 is "a", or "b"
- the options for position2 is "p", or "q"

then you can simply use the builtin itertools to get the product of these lists

```py
import itertools
print(["".join(s) for s in itertools.product(*subs)])
#['sbp', 'sbq', 'sap', 'saq']
```

Comment: Slight variation for deterministic result order: `subs = [_x+replacements.get(_x,'') for _x in x]` (then the result starts with 'sap' instead of 'sbp' or others)

Answer (score 2):

Going through the word, applying each letter's replacement (if any):

```
x_result = [x]
for i, c in enumerate(x):
    if d := replacements.get(c):
        x_result += [w[:i] + d + w[i+1:] for w in x_result]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVFLTsQwDBXbnsK7tGpBYoci9SRVNGo7LkSapGmSqkWIk7CZDWy4EafB-RQNWcTPfs-fxB9f5tW_zPp6_Vz9dP_0c_dt0Vz6ERVq76CFN9YzzgbWAF2cHAKKgA5AE1ABGAJLAAsBw96LwqOL-V0BdErmekN8ly2ZKHdD8oaFiarJUpWlyZKJUpWkaoieTpxOnE6czmVEUUyzhb0B3A2OHqSGOA-PHfaTRbdefJhuFzEU5LKBMShRrwpt77Hcq5QQjpzgDLyF2-95eEZfjjeif9VrKr91XAqoKbWGrZP1Ixex1xYaHco0grFS-9LN1uO5PKgK2hZyLL2lav7yqrSzvLpjhb8)

Comment: I had to check if it works in python. if d := replacements.get(c): how does it work?

Comment: @shantanuo Tries to get a replacement for the character, assigns it (or `None`) to `d`, and goes into the `if` body if there is a replacement (since the replacements are true but `None` isn't).